# есть ли способ определить наличие fatal error в js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Существует ли способ определить есть ли какие нибудь ошибки в выполнении js кода, не именно по конкретной функции или переменной а в целом

Comment: можете все в `try-catch` обернуть) А вообще, не понятно, что вам нужно и зачем. Возможно, есть другие способы решения

Comment: @ThisMan Ага, особенно асинхронную функцию в `try-catch` обернуть.

Comment: @ThisMan да и даже при последовательном выполнении, тот же Segmentation fault вы не перехватите.

Comment: ну причина в том что в скрипте есть функция animate которая передвигает блоки меняя свойство left но когда браузер под нагрузкой она не срабаывает и это происходит когда вылезают ошибки которые выводятся в консоли, это так случается только в хром а обрабатывать скрпиты из за которых ошибки нет возомжности по каждой переменной или функции

Comment: @misha11 что за ошибки? Если браузер тормозит, то он не станет ошибки кидать

Comment: @Suvitruf тот же `async/await` хорошо ложится под `try-catch`

Comment: ну ошибки выдает разные в консоли, непонятна причина такого бага, эта функция работает таким образом: 4 блока располгаются в видмой части а затем добавляется еще одна с позицией left :100% (absolute) а потом все блоки сдвигаются при помощи animate() а при нагрузке на браузер функция animate не  срабатывает и когда в результате блоки наползают друг на друга тов консоли всегда видна ошибка